# How to use jsdoc to describe export default ({ Label, initialValue, })=>{ ... }

Tags: jsdoc

How to use jsdoc to describe export default ({
Label,
initialValue,
})=>{
...
}

How to use jsdoc to describe export default ({
Label,
initialValue,
})=>{
...
}

Comment: Can you improve your question a bit

Comment: How to use jsdoc to describe the anonymous function module exported by es6 and the elaboration of the function is a literal object. for example： export default ({ Label, initialValue, })=>{ ... }